# Why does my LocationListener become null?

Tags: android, location, locationmanager, locationlistener

I am having issues regarding a `LocationListener` in my Service called `myService`.

Here is my code:

```
///onStart method ..
onStart() {
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE)
    .
    .
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    locationListener = (LocationListener) new MyLocationListener();
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 0, locationListener);
}
```

In my Activity there is a button which should stop the service.  On the click of the button I am doing:

```
stopService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), myService.class)
```

In the `myService.java` file I have:

```
////onDestroy method....
onDestroy() {
    locationManager=(LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener); //Getting **exception here ....
}
```

I get the following Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: listener==null at android.location.LocationManager.removeUpdates(LocationManager.java:799) at 
<.package_name>myService.onDestroy(myService.java:407)
```

I don't know why listener turns null without reason.  Please can you tell me where I am going wrong!

Comment: Are you manually setting it to null someplace else in the code?

Comment: i am sure that am not setting it to null . i think service is restarted , but i dont understand which part of code it gets executed  when the service does restart.

Answer (score 1):

The Android system will force-stop a service only when memory is low and it must recover system resources for the activity that has user focus. If the service is bound to an activity that has user focus, then it's less likely to be killed, and if the service is declared to run in the foreground (discussed later), then it will almost never be killed. Otherwise, if the service was started and is long-running, then the system will lower its position in the list of background tasks over time and the service will become highly susceptible to killing—if your service is started, then you must design it to gracefully handle restarts by the system. If the system kills your service, it restarts it as soon as resources become available again (though this also depends on the value you return from onStartCommand(), as discussed later). For more information about when the system might destroy a service, see the Processes and Threading document.

Answer (score 0):

I could be off here, but it seems like maybe your Service is being killed then (later) restarted. Why not move the instantiation stuff into `onCreate()`?

Comment: thanks for the ans. can u please brief what may be the reasons/causes for the service to restart.